# HTML- how may i align left and right in same line-

Tags: html

http://sunprojects.co.il/

I want the logo will be on the right, and phone number on the left middle

How do I do this?

Comment: put your codes here please

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want seperate elements, one floated left and one floated right.

Something like this HTML:

```
<div class="header-number">
    <p>012345 678901</p>
</div>
<div class="header-logo">
    <img src="headerlogo.png" />
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.header-number{
    float: left;
}
.header-logo{
    float: right;
}
```

You can read more about floats here [w3schools CSS Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Comment: Where do I put the CSS

Comment: @user1461642 In a seperate stylesheet. You can read about CSS, including how to include your CSS style sheets, here: http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code for http://sunprojects.co.il/

```
<style type="text/css">.phone_number{float: left;top:110px;position: relative;}</style>
<span class="phone_number">
 <font size="10" color="white">0504663343</font>
</span>
```

Comment: This is some partial the markup copied from the site's source. It only shows the phone number (not the logo) and doesn't really explain how to reproduce it.

Comment: he just wanna middle the phone number on left middle, logo already in right position so i didn't add the logo code.